# Incorrect use of react hooks but no hook errors/faults

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

React hooks can only be used inside

- Functional components
- Other hooks

If you don't follow the above rules, react complains about not following the rules via a fault

But, the below code works (albeit with lint errors) without any stack-trace/errors

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";

const SomethingContext = createContext("what is the thing");

// Correct usage
const useSomething = () => {
  const something = useContext(SomethingContext);
  return something;
};

//Incorrect usage
const getTheThing = () => {
  const theThing = useContext(SomethingContext); // works with useState as well (ex below)
  return theThing;
};

//Incorect usage
const getTheThingState = () => {
  const [theThing, setTheThing] = useState("I am the state"); 
  return theThing;
};

const Child = () => {
  const theThing = getTheThing(); //OR getTheThingState()
  return `The thing is "${theThing}"`;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SomethingContext.Provider value={"it is something"}>
        <Child />
      </SomethingContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-bird-nu8ep) of the above code. The linter points out the incorrect usage, but the odd part where I'm confused is that `React` itself doesn't throw any error.

Not able to figure out **WHY?**

All resources point out to fix the above problem by changing the function into a component i.e function's variable name (I'm aware of it)

```
const GetTheThing = () => {
//...
```

But, when does react decide to say "okay, you are not supposed to do that" vs "okay, I'll let this one slide".

Answer (score -1):

Technically there is no problem with the code provided. As the invocation of `useContext` and `useState` happening inside component's code. And there is no issue of having one outer function, which just calls the hook inside. Yes, we are breaking the [Only Call Hooks at the Top Level](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) rule. But if you go through [rationale behind this rule](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation) - you'll see that the ordering of invocations is the key here. And having function without any nested `if` statements still guarantees the ordering. So your code:

```
export const useSomething = () => {
  const something = useContext(SomethingContext);
  return something;
};

const getTheThing = () => {
  const theThing = useSomething();
  return theThing;
};

const Child = () => {
  const theThing = getTheThing();
  return `The thing is "${theThing}"`;
};
```

Still complies with correct ordering of:

- Render fn of `Child` component started
- `useContext` invoked
- Render fn of `Child` component finished

Comment: `App` is a component, `Child` is a component. And i havn't used the hook inside either of these components. It's used outside these FC's i.e it's a plain function. The error is not a false positive. I know all the possible solutions for the above code, but intent is to know how it's working as expected despite not following the "Rules of hooks"

Comment: You can try moving the `getTheThing` into it's own file (and import it in `App.js`) and the code won't change i.e it'll still continue to work with the linter error.

Comment: I've updated the code for you, in case you want to try.

Comment: I've updated the answer to be more precise. Calling a hook in nested fn (but still in render of your Component) is a "soft" rule and only have effect if the ordering of hook invocations become broken. What is not the case in your example.